# RSpec controller spec unable to update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I have a Rails/RSpec controller spec that is throwing the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `completed_set_url' for #<CompletedSetsController:0x007fcfe935c5d0>
from /Users/arelenglish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:268:in `handle_model_call'
```

The line `put :update, {id: completed_set.to_param, completed_set: valid_attributes}` is where it's blowing up. I don't know what the completed_set_url method is, or why/where it is being called.

The entire spec is below:

```
it "assigns the requested completed_set as @completed_set" do
  completed_set = CompletedSet.create! valid_attributes
  put :update, {id: completed_set.to_param, completed_set: valid_attributes}
  expect(assigns(:completed_set)).to eq(completed_set)
end
```

For completeness, here is my controller code:

```
class CompletedSetsController < BaseController
  before_action :set_completed_set, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /completed_sets
  def create
    @completed_set = CompletedSet.new(completed_set_params)
    if @completed_set.save
      redirect_to profile_path, notice: 'Successfully completed set.'
    else
      raise "Failed to save because #{@completed_set.errors.each {|e| e}}"
    end
  end

  # PUT /completed_sets/1
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @completed_set.update_attributes(completed_set_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @completed_set, notice: 'Completed set was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # User callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_completed_set
      @completed_set = CompletedSet.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def completed_set_params
      params.require(:completed_set).permit(
        :repetitions, 
        :set_number, 
        :user_id, 
        :weight, 
        :user_program_id, 
        :rpe, 
        :workout_exercise_id,
        :workout_exercise_set_id 
        )
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being called from `redirect_to @completed_set` in your `update` action.

The issue here is that your `update` action redirects to `@completed_set` (`completed_set_url`) when it's successful, but your app doesn't define a `show` action for that resource.

So, in your `config/routes.rb` file, define a show action (maybe using `resources :completed_set`, if your controller is RESTful), then define a `show` method in your controller, or change the `redirect_to` to be the same as your `create` action (`redirect_to profile_path`).

Comment: I don't want a show action. a user creates a completed_set from their profile page, and that portion of the profile page is reloaded.

Comment: Updated to remove the need for a `show` action (just redirect to your `profile_path` instead).

Comment: Thank you! I must have been looking at this way too long. I completely missed that.